# Zend Mail (Using SMTP) : Email addresses from CC appearing in TO

Tags: zend-framework, email, smtp

I am having a weird problem using Zend Mail with my SMTP server. I am trying to send an email with to List and CC List and the unique email recipients in the CC list are being added to the To List of the email.

I was trying to debug this by dumping the Zend_Mail object and here is what it looks like:

```
[_charset:protected] => iso-8859-1
[_headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [From] => Array
            (
                [0] => me@from.com
                [append] => 1
            )

        [To] => Array
            (
                [0] => epinapala@gmail.com
                [append] => 1
                [1] => epinapala@f.com
            )

        [Cc] => Array
            (
                [0] => epinapala@d.com
                [append] => 1
                [1] => epinapala@m.com
            )

        [Subject] => Array
            (
                [0] => Mail Subject Here 
            )

    )

[_headerEncoding:protected] => quoted-printable
[_from:protected] => me@from.com
[_to:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => epinapala@gmail.com
        [1] => epinapala@f.com
    )


[_recipients:protected] => Array
    (
        [epinapala@gmail.com] => 1
        [epinapala@f.com] => 1
        [epinapala@d.com] => 1
        [epinapala@m.com] => 1
    )
```

The Mail headers look good but however the emails in the CC list are being added to To List.

All I am doing is appending email to the ToList and CC List.

```
   $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    ................... 
......................
    $mail->setFrom($from);
    $mail->addTo("epinapala@gmail.com");
    $mail->addTo("epinapala@f.com");
    $mail->addCc("epinapala@d.com");
    $mail->addCc("epinapala@m.com");
.......................
..........
    $mail->send();
```

Below is the screenshot from my Gmail showing the problem: **@d.com and @m.com are appearing in to as well!**

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Should work, but you can try to add both (TO/CC) as arrays insted of 4 function calls: ->addTo(array('1','2'); ->addCc(array('1', '2'))

Comment: Last idea: Add "Names" to the CC Field like ->addCc('mail@mail.de', 'Name of user');

Comment: That dint work either .. I dont think the names are mandatory!

Comment: OK! I think there a lot of Problems with this inside the Zend Framework Versions. Try to use a Version above 1.10. Here are some issues on the bug trackeR: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-928, http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3362

Comment: Sorry to say, But the current version I am using is 1.11 , And i tried 1.12 too, No luck :(

Comment: Crazy will try this today on my environment

Comment: So tested it: Works perfect with Zend Framework 1.12, possible an error with your Mailserver?

Comment: I am having same issue now with zend 1.12.16. Did you manage to fix it?